# How to effectively use explicit argument names to clear up "magic numbers" in this polymorphic context

Tags: c++, static, readability

I have this code:

```
    class Base
    {
        public:
          Base(int attributeA, int attributeB, int attributeC) : attributeA_(attributeA),
              attributeB_(attributeB), attributeC_(attributeC) {}
        private:
          int attributeA_;
          int attributeB_;
          int attributeC_;
    }
```

And then I have a couple child classes like this

```
class ChildA : public Base
{
   public:
     ChildA() : Base(1, 2, 3) {} // magic values
}

class ChildB : public Base
{
   public:
     ChildB() : Base(4, 1, 7) {} // magic values
}
```

t's hard for me to remember what arguments go in what order (they aren't actually called A B C so when I see `Base(4, 1, 7)`, I might say "What is 1 doing already?". A solution I came up with is the following:

```
class ChildA : public Base
{
   public:
     ChildA() : Base(attributeA, attributeB, attributeC) {} // no magic values
   private:
     static constexpr int attributeA = 1;
     static constexpr int attributeB = 2;
     static constexpr int attributeC = 3;
}

class ChildB : public Base
{
   public:
     ChildB() : Base(attributeA, attributeB, attributeC) {} // no magic values
   private:
     static constexpr int attributeA = 4;
     static constexpr int attributeB = 1;
     static constexpr int attributeC = 7;
}
```

And now it's crystal clear that when I see 1 in ChildB's call the Base, I know it will be set to attributeB. I'm unsure this is a great solution because ChildA and B already have access to the protected values of Base `attributeA_` and so forth as well as the private static declarations. This means that from the child classes we have two different variables to access the same value.

Since these variables are only used once, I was thinking on just putting them in the header file. Such as

child_b.h:

```
  static constexpr int attributeA = 4;
  static constexpr int attributeB = 1;
  static constexpr int attributeC = 7;

class ChildB : public Base
{
   public:
     ChildB() : Base(attributeA, attributeB, attributeC) {} 
}
```

That way, ChildB can only access the attributeB with the protected variable from Base `attributeB_`. This solution works fine for one child class, but if I do this for multiple header files and include them there's redefinition conflicts (since they have the same name). Is there a good way for me to have these argument hints without having the data accessible twice inside of the class? I guess I could do the second solution and use `static constexpr int childBattributeB = 1`. Alternatively, perhaps my concern is not that bad and I should just roll with my first solution. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't like `attributeA` etc in the global namespace.  I would go with your 1st solution but call each initial value a slightly different name eg `static constexpr int initAttributeA = 4;`

Comment: A decent IDE will show you the names of the parameters.  That's how I live with my flaky memory.

Comment: The only way is to define these constants in different namespaces.

Comment: [Named parameters](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/) might interest you.

Comment: Document your code.  Most IDE will present you with you documentation when hovering above a function call or a variable.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy The trouble with that is, you have to keep it up to date, and you never do.

Comment: @PaulSanders  I don't see how creating a myriad of undocumented classes solely because the original class is not documented properly is not a waste of time and effort.  This time and effort would be much better spent by adding 3 lines of comment, total time : 30 seconds.   Figuring out what is the purpose of these classes that do not provide ANY new functionality could take quite a bit more time than that, every single time the code is read.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I agree with you (about the extra classes), it wasn't me who shared that link.  But, as I say, a decent IDE will show you the parameter names anyway, so repeating that information in a comment (unless the meaning is not obvious from the name) is, IMO, not a good idea.

Comment: @Cedric I hope you realize that adding classes to name parameters is not a good idea, to the point that you should expect a co-worker will eventually delete your code.  How about documenting the code, renaming the original parameters to something useful, or using named constants and pass these as parameters at the call site?  There are plenty of more effective solutions until you get used to the code you have to work with and can recall by heart how classes work.  That WILL eventually happen.  By the way, using named contants is the recommended way of getting rid of "magic numbers" .

Comment: @PaulSanders  I agree with you on the parameter names being sufficient in most cases.  But some applications do require some documentation, in particular, if you want to publish your code as open-source, no one will use open-source code that's not at least minimally documented.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I think we have reached agreement, I have no argument with any of that.